# Does Azure AD B2C allow group hierarchies?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I was just playing with Azure AD B2C UI in the Portal, and to my amazement I was unable to add a group to a group. I thought this might have been a glitch with my browser, but when I searched for "Nested groups" in relation to AD, I saw this come up as a feature request!

The function to Add Group to a Group in the Portal does actually 'work.' I even get a notification saying "add group member successful," but the group does not appear anywhere in the lists.

Am I correct in thinking that nesting groups is not offered by AD??? I actually really need this, and right now it's looking like the only way to implement group hierarchies is via Directory Extensions? Is this correct? What other workarounds can I have? It is looking increasingly likely that Azure AD/B2C cannot be a fit for our needs, and I am going to have a real hard time selling this internally if basic functions like group hierarchies are unavailable.

Comment: Azure AD B2C has very limited support for groups - is there something you are looking to do with nested groups? The best workaround I can think of is to store group information in your own database.

Comment: Just discovered this today, does anyone know if the graph API call to add a group to a group would work ?

Comment: @user1197653 At time of writing, after some research, nested groups did not work. I don't know if since then some feature was added. However, after more work in the area (eventually using a custom version of ASP.NET Identity instead of AD), it became apparent that group hierarchies were not an adequate model for rights inheritance as new use cases were discovered. I strongly advise to rethink the need for group hierarchy rights inheritance and look at other more flexible models.

Answer (score 0):

Azure AD B2C supports very large scale directories, which can handle hundreds of millions of objects if not more. To scale to such a level, there are some compromises that had to be made, one of which was disallowing nested groups at arbitrarily multiple levels.

Groups are supported in Azure AD B2C but without nesting. The API should ideally return an error, and it is likely a bug that it's not giving a clear error.